# setting the height of a div using CSS

Tags: css, height, html

I'm having a problem with setting the height of `<div>` tags using CSS.

I'm using the following CSS & HTML code.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" />
<title></title>
</head>
<style>
body, p, b, ul, li, div
{
padding:0;
margin:0;
border:0;
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
div
{
display:block;
}

#ph_container
{
margin:0 auto;
width:980px;
height:auto;
border: 1px solid  #00CC33;
clear:both;
background: #F0F0F0;
}

#cp_search
{
height:100px;
clear:both;
margin:10px 0px 0px 0px;
border: 1px solid #0099FF;
}

#cp_search_ex
{
clear:both;
background:none;
margin-top:5px;
margin-left:27px;

}
#cp_search_tx
{
width:210px;
float:left; /*try here whitout float and see the difference that I want to get*/
margin:0px;
background:none;
}

.txtx
{
color: #000000;
text-decoration:none;
font-size:13px;
font-weight:bold;
}
</style>
<body>

<div id="ph_container" class="space">
     <div id="cp_search">
        <div id="cp_search_ex" class="space"> 
          <div id="cp_search_tx" class="txtx" >SEARCH</div>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

My problem is that the parent `div id="cp_search_ex"` doesn't get the height of the `div id="cp_search_tx"` which is inside it, it has the `height: 0px`.

I want  the `div id="cp_search_ex"` to take the height from the `div id="cp_search_tx"`?

I wrote a comment in the CSS code please follow.

Comment: in your comment under the code, you mean "cp_search_ex" and "cp_searched_tx", right? You don't have the id's "p_search_ex" or "cp_search"txt"

Comment: What is your goal? Do you want your outer div take 100% of the height?

Comment: @ImportedNoob,  At first I thought I messed up my edit but those simply look like typos in the question description.  The identifiers in his HTML code match his CSS code.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't think that you need to use `div{display:block;}` as `display:block;` is the default for `<div>`s.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use a `clearfix` method. I usually use

```
.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
    content: ' ';
    display: block;
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
}

* html .clearfix,
*:first-child+html .clearfix {
    zoom: 1;
}
```

Apply the class clearfix to `ph_container` and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Clearing floats does not need to be this complicated!

Comment: @Sparky672 - you're right, it doesn't! http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/

Comment: @motoxer4533, simply adding `overflow:hidden` to the parent of the floating `div` will also cause it to fully expand to encompass its floating contents, thereby eliminating any need for a `clear`-ing `div` or a "clearfix" workaround.

Comment: @Sparky672 - Thanks, didn't know that. Will try it out in future. Any idea why `overflow:hidden` makes the parent expand to the size of the children? I thought floating effectively took the children out of the scope of the parent elem.

Answer (score 1):

try adding this to the style for the parent divs (so they wholly-contain their floated children):

```
overflow:hidden;
```

pretty complex post - it would help if you could pare it down to a specific example that exhibits the problem you're having.

Comment: Yes. Adding an overflow attribute to a parent element will force it to contain any floated children.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are describing the problem solved by using a "[clearfix](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/)".

Answer (score 1):

You have at least one error in your CSS.  You've set the height twice...

```
#ph_container{
   margin:0 auto;
   width:980px;
   height:auto; /* duplicated height */
   border: 1px solid  #00CC33;
   clear:both;
   background: #F0F0F0;
   height:100%;  /* duplicated height */
}
```

So if you want the parent to take the height of its *content*, then you need to remove `height:100%` as that is telling the parent to be 100% of whatever is just *outside* the parent... in your case, that's 100% of the `body`'s height.

And `cp_search_tx` cannot expand the size of its container since it's a `float:`.  [By definition](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#floats), floats are outside of the normal content flow and therefore their container elements will appear to be empty.

Add an empty clearing `div` under the content which forces the container `div` to dynamically expand.

```
<div id="cp_search_ex" class="space"> 
    <div id="cp_search_tx" class="txtx" >SEARCH</div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

Alternatively, simply adding `overflow:hidden` to the container will also force it to expand to encompass any floats.

Answer (score -1):

The question does not really make much sense, the outer block takes 100px + margin, so it works.

The text element has float defined so it doesn't take space.

Comment: Please explain what `position:absolute` has to do with any of this.

Comment: I don't understand what is the problem, what do you try to achieve? The absolute position will make the 100% height take 100% of the available screen. The div of the parent takes the 100 pix + margin height in your example after I cut&pasted it, so I don't see a problem there.

Comment: I am not the OP.  The OP seems to be asking about how to make a container expand in height to encompass its contents.  Changing the container to `position:absolute` will do nothing here other than take it out of the normal flow.

Comment: It does expand in height. He has height:100% on the outer element, I thought that's the goal - make it 100% height. Position: absolute will help with that.

Comment: I think you should read the question again.  Container is set to `100%`... its content is set to `100px`.  OP wrote: _"parent div doesn't get the height of the div which is inside it"_

Comment: but it does get the hight of 100px + margin.